# HTTPS and SSL handshake issue and Event log Fatal Alert 80 in .net

Tags: vb.net, ssl

I am having vb6 code which is running under VS2005. This is windows based application.

Issue: There were some Microsoft security patch updates applied on client machines. After those patches applications are not running. When we remove the patches applications are running fine.

Application is accessing remote service for authentication and other service calls (Third Party).

Done the below steps

1. When I ran the application there is an error in Event logs:

> ```
>   Fatal alert:80
> ```

2. I used fiddler tool I got response message like HTTPS handshake issue. Certificate issue. I didn't understand this. because application is running since long years without any issue.
3. I read related article in Microsoft forums: As per my investigation we have found the event log error Fatal alert:80 somehow related to certificate expiration after installation of new patches. 
   (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/kb2992611-and-schannel-internalerror-during/20b3270b-45e3-4002-8f31-8bd0430ba080)
4. I tried my level best to implement to bypass the certificate verification but is also not working as expected

Config level

Added settings like Certificate check false. But not useful

Code Level
Step 1 Login Page : Login Button
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = New GEPUIS_MTS_Objects.trustedCertificatePolicy

Step 2:  Check authentication calling the service names and server details

Calling this method check_authentication()  inside this method passing user id and password to third party

```
Method check_authentication()
{
   MTS_Objects.authenticate(sUserID, sPassword)
try
    MTS_Objects.Author(sUserID, sPassword, SAppl, ServerName)
}


Public Sub authenticate(ByVal user As String, ByVal password As String)
        Dim filter As OmniSwitchOutputFilter
        Dim coll As SoapOutputFilterCollection
        filter = New OmniSwitchOutputFilter(user, password)
        coll = WebServicesConfiguration.FilterConfiguration.OutputFilters
        coll.Clear()
        coll.Add(filter)
    End Sub


  Public Sub Author(ByVal user As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal MyAppl As String, ByVal serverName As String)
        Dim InputUser As New com.XXXX.XXX.XXXX.soap.UserSecurity.UserAuth_T()
        Dim MyHeader As New com.XXXX.XXX.XXXX.soap.UserSecurity.Header_T()
        Dim authManager As AuthManager
        Dim url As Uri
        Dim principal As System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal

        Select Case serverName

            Case "UNIT RE (XXXX)"
                'url = New Uri("https://XXXX.z.XXX.XXXX.com:portnumber/is2/AuthService")
                url = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UNITRE").ToString())

        End Select
        **authManager = New AuthManager(url)**
        Try
            **principal = authManager.authenticate(user, password, "")**

        Catch ex As TransportException
            Throw New Exception("TransportException occured: " + ex.Message)
        Catch ex As AuthManagerException
            Throw New Exception("AuthManagerException occured: " + ex.Message)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            Throw New Exception("Exception occured: " + ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim x As ISFIdentity
        x = principal.Identity
    End Sub
End Module
```

Calling this method authManager.authenticate(user, password, "")  This method passing to below c. class. We are able make a call to below method getting True also with clear certificate information in without patching machine. I can't able to debug in TEST machine because I don't have VS.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net

Public Class trustedCertificatePolicy
    Implements ICertificatePolicy
    Public Sub trustedCertificatePolicy()

    End Sub

    Public Function CheckValidationResult(ByVal srvPoint As ServicePoint, ByVal cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal request As WebRequest, ByVal problem As Integer) As Boolean Implements ICertificatePolicy.CheckValidationResult

        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

The request is going to make a call to CheckValidationResult method but I am not getting response.

I am consuming CORBA Services. As per mainframes team they are not able to see the request from       the application.

This is readonly application. I am able run this application without the patching machine. This is running under windows 2007 OS.

This is only I can give inputs from my end. This issue i am facing since 10 days.

It might be certificate issue. But is there any possibility to bypass the certificate validation.

Comment: This is pretty unclearly phrased. What configuration changes did you try, in detail? Are "remote" and "CORBA" services referring only to the same thing? What's Windows 2007? And what's with that bizarre C-like code in the middle of VB6 running on VB.NET???

Comment: Please only use indentation for code, not for text.

Comment: Also, VB6 doesn't run in VS2005.

Comment: Your code is not VB6 but VB.Net